# Where does Laravel 5.3 keep the Auth data?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, laravel-5

Ok, I have some custom Auth happening in my app. And we've got a working register controller, however calling the Auth::facade at the moment is calling the wrong table. Since I have two authentication tables, not just the default users table, how do I register a separate Auth facade to call the new Auth table.

The documentation doesn't seem to cover Multi-Auth scenarios clearly.

I'd like to be able to call something like this:

```
 if (Auth::attempt(['Username' => $request['Username'], 'Password' => $request['Password']])) {
            return redirect()->route('agencydash');
        }
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

And instead of checking the users table (which it currently does), I'd like to check a table for companies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, You should add a new guard when you want to use separate table/model for authentication. It can be done in your `config/auth.php` file.

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'company' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'companies',
    ]
],

...

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'companies' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'table' => App\Company::class,
    ],
],
```

Then, you can use custom guard while authenticating the users.

```
if (Auth::guard('company')->attempt($credentials)) {
    //
}
```

Ref - Check **Accessing Specific Guard Instances** [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#authenticating-users)

Comment: Yeah that helps put two and two together. Cheers.